# Sketch the parametrised curve $C = \{(1-e^{-t},e^{-2t}):t\in [0,\infty]\}$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, curves, parametrization

**Exercise:** Sketch the parametrised curve $C = \{(1-e^{-t},e^{-2t}):t\in [0,\infty]\}$.

*What I've tried:* If you let $f(t) = \begin{bmatrix}1 - e^{-t}\\e^{-2t}\end{bmatrix}$ then for $t = 0,1,2,\ldots$ you get $$f(0) = \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}, \,f(1) = \begin{bmatrix}1 - e^{-1}\\e^{-2}\end{bmatrix},\,f(2) = \begin{bmatrix}1 - e^{-2}\\e^{-4}\end{bmatrix},\ldots$$

Since I wasn't able to make anything of this myself, I used the [Wolfram parametric curve plotter](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=ddaa2332531af389fba463a032fcec9d), but it said that I didn't enter a valid input.

**Question:** How do I sketch this parametrised curve? Why is wolfram telling me that this input is incorrect? Surely I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what it is.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps that you meant $t\in[0,\infty]$ instead of $\mu\in[0,\infty]$.

Comment: @Dair I know, but I'm not using $\cos (t)$ or $\sin (t)$ right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$x(t)= 1-\exp(-t)$$
$$y(t)=\exp(-2t)=\left[\exp(-t)  \right]^2$$

Solve the first equation for $\exp(-t)$ and plug it into the second equation to obtain $y(x)$.

Also, think about all possible values of $x$? What domain is admissible for $x$?

Comment: ... giving a parabola ; I wouldn't say "solve for"; I would say "set $T=exp(-t)$ which gives a new parameterization of the curve : $x=1-T ; y=T^2$